# Обязательные параметры функции javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Возможно ли делать параметры функции обязательными?

вот например класс

```
class Test {

   func(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
       // some code...   
   }
}

let test = new Test();
test.func(10, 20); //если не передан хотя-бы один аргумент то кидать исключение
```

Возможно ли это решить с помощью es6 js при этом не юзать костыли? Какое решение в нативном скрипте для таких задач

Comment: нет, только проверять внутри функции сколько именно параметров пришло

Comment: @Grundy хм... странно, я думал они предусмотрели такую ситуацию в es6

Comment: Увы, только значение по умолчанию можно прилепить... или костыль в виде `arg3 = throwIfMissing() `  где `throwIfMissing()` является функцией (методом)  `function throwIfMissing() {
        throw new Error('Missing parameter');
    }`

Comment: За возможность творить что хочешь почти без последствий, которые давно задушили бы большинство языков, тут надо платить дополнительными ручными проверками. Вариант @АлексейШиманский классный :) `function throwIfMissing(name){throw new Error('Missing "' + name + '" argument!');} function t(f, s = throwIfMissing('s')){console.info(f,s);} t(1); // Uncaught Error: Missing "s" argument!`

Comment: @Other лепить такое на сотни функций как-то не вариант))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, другого варианта нет. Есть, правда, возможность задать в `JSDoc` какой-либо маркер и пусть сборщик добавляет проверку сам.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мда работает, но функция стала громадной Годзилой с 5 аргументами ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что классы ES6 - по сути не привносят ничего нового. Это просто декорации - на старые добрые прототипы. Есть конечно несколько "допилов" синтакиса, вроде параметров по-умолчанию. Поэтому - нет, необязательность всех параметров, очень закоренелая концепция JS.

Comment: Понял )) тогда буду рассматривать TypeScript как будущее решение )

Comment: @modelfak по мне JS хорош и без TypeScript . В ES6 просто выправили наконец ну очень уж некрасивое ООП - молодцы. Правда в TS есть грандиозная вещь, union types - за это ему звезду, и статус "юзать можно" :)